# Unable to hide div using js, but I'm able to show div with js. Seems like "else if" isn't working. Could someone look over this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that I can show with js, but I can't seem to close. Using if .... else if...
For example:

```
<a id="downgrade" onclick="showDowngradeDiv()" href="javascript:void(0)"><h1>Downgrade ▼</h1></a>
<div id="downgrade-text">
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>A paragraph of text</p>
</div>
```

```
function showDowngradeDiv() {
  const DowngradeDiv = document.getElementById("downgrade-text");

  if (DowngradeDiv.style.display = "none") {
    DowngradeDiv.style.display = "block";
  } 
  else if (DowngradeDiv.style.display = "block") {
    DowngradeDiv.style.display = "none";
    alert("test");
  }
}
```

```
#downgrade-text {
  display: none;
}
```

If anyone has any idea, let me know because I don't know what I'm doing wrong here right now.

Comment: use == instead  of = and also just use else why else if ??

Comment: Like @lhbibhbart stated.... and... Unless you set `Element.style.display = 'block'` *(or 'none')* JavaScript won't know what it is. I recommend having a `.hide{ display:none; }` CSS class and using `Element.classList.add` and `Element.classList.remove`, storing a display variable at a higher scope in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the display property at the if/else. Please use the double equal sign operator.

```
if (DowngradeDiv.style.display = "none") 

if (DowngradeDiv.style.display == "none")
```

Comment: Also, No need to do the else if, Just else.

Comment: If I change it to
```
  if (DowngradeDiv.style.display == "none") {
    DowngradeDiv.style.display = "block";
  } 
  else {
    DowngradeDiv.style.display = "none";
    alert("huh");
  }
}
```
it doesn't work it just alerts "huh" even though the display is set to none with css

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, just messed around with js and ended up doing this and somehow it's working?

```
function showDowngradeDiv() {
  const DowngradeDiv = document.getElementById("downgrade-text");

  if (DowngradeDiv.style.display == "block") {
    DowngradeDiv.style.display = "none";
  } 
  else {
    DowngradeDiv.style.display = "block";
    DowngradeDiv.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  }
}
```

but if I were to switch the statements around and say if Downgrade.style.display == "none" then change it to block and scroll to it else set display to none. That wouldn't work for some reason, but flipping it seems to have gotten me what I wanted functionally.